# how do you get the id or url of the resource that's being updated when handling an Update_Of_Resource notification?

Tags: onem2m

When handling a `Update_Of_Resource` notification, when the subscription's `notificationContentType` is set to `Modified Attribute`, how does one get the `Id` or `Url` of the resource being updated?

Answer (score 1):

According to TS-0001, table 10.2.10.7-1: Notification Procedure, the **content** of the notification shall include the subscription reference that generates the notification, i.e. the address of the corresponding subscription.

The shortname for *subscriptionReference* is **sur**

Generally speaking, when you create a subscription you should retain the resource address of the subscription so that you can compare the value recieved in the notification with the value recieved in the notification.

You can use this as part of your notification handler to determine what actions to take.

Comment: yeah, that's what i thought. seems like a big hole to require the AE to keep its own mapping just to be able to link notifications with the notified resource. it would have been much simpler if either the notification included the resource Id, or even better, if it was possible to put some AE-defined identifier in the subscription such that all the notification included that value.

Comment: The "modified attributes" option is for optimisation. Optimisation usually means that you have to keep track of other necessary information elsewhere. When your AE cannot do the association for whatever reasons then your subscription should be configured   with the "attributes" result content type to receive the full resource, including the resource ID etc

Comment: That is a good idea/suggestion - "possible to put some AE-defined identifier in the subscription such that all the notification included that value"

Comment: What if the same subscription is configured to notify multiple AEs? Wouldn't it be better to always include the ri instead of another/foreign id?